# Why do images become distorted (not lowe res) when exporting Powerpoint to pdf?

Tags: pdf, powerpoint

I am trying to export a PowerPoint deck to pdf, but I keep having issues with images in "SmartArt".

This is what is in the PowerPoint (low res due to screenshot; this is just one of the eight pictures on that slide):

[image]

But whenever I export, I get something like this (see lower 1/4 of picture; that part is "junk" and the rest has been moved up):

[image]

And it's much worse for other pictures I have added. I have tried high-res and lower res images, I have tried jpg, tiff, png, or pdf format for the pictures, but it doesn't help.

Also, it is not consistent. I can change the picture, and it might export correctly, and instead a different picture on the slide will distort. Going back and forth (deleting the picture and inserting ***the same picture***), I might be lucky and get one export where they all look good, but it might not happen until attempt #50 (or at all), so that's not really a viable solution.

I'm on macOS 14.1 with PowerPoint v16.78. This has been an issue on previous versions of both macOS and PowerPoint, though.

Any ideas of how to make this work?